# MySql Workbench stored procedure missing after refreshing

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySql Workbench 6.2 and I created this simple stored procedure in MySql Workbench

```
USE `MyDB`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `new_procedure2`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `MyDB`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure2` ()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Country (BaseName) VALUES('Canada');
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Creation succeded, but if I refresh in MySql Workbench, Sotred procedure disapear. I opened PhpMyAdmin and I can see stored procedure. Do you have any idea why it disapear in MySql Workbench?

EDIT:
MySQL (from Xampp) is installed on another PC. 
I installed MySQL Workbench on the PC where MySQL is installed and can't see stored procedure too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I downgraded to version 6.1.7 and its working. I tried 6.2 32 and 64 bits but neither is showing my stored procedure. It look like its a bug in the last version at this date...